# Multiple inside SQL Commands

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to use another sql command in the sql command. I would rather draw the x and y values ​​from another table. How do I integrate these two values ​​into that sql command? So I want to pull data from a different table.

X VALUES = `SELECT X_VALUES FROM ...TBL_STT`

Y VALUES = `SELECT Y_VALUES FROM ...TBL_STT`

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT ADI_SOYADI, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(x) ) * cos( radians( ENLEM ) ) * cos( radians( BOYLAM ) - radians(y) ) + sin( radians(x) ) * sin( radians( ENLEM ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM ...TBL_MUSTERILER HAVING distance < 25000000000 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 40";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $all_rows = $result->fetch_all();
} else {
}
echo json_encode($all_rows);
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Because of the `LIMIT` usage i assume you are using MySQL/MariaDB/PostgreSQL as RDMS ? As this SQL code is not valid ANSI/ISO Standard SQL

Comment: *"How do I integrate these two values ​​into that sql command? So I want to pull data from a different table."* ... see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I'm using mysql. @RaymondNijland